# Cointegration test, three I(1) variables, and one I(0) variable

Tags: time-series, cointegration

I have four time series, three of which are I(1), and one is I(0). 
I know an I(0) and an I(1) timeseries can not be cointegrated, but if I run a Johansen test could the other I(1) variables be cointegrated with eachother?

Or, does it consider all four variables, and as one is I(0), then there is no linear combination that would be stationary, and therefore, there would be no cointegrating relationships present.

Comment: Hopefully someone else can provide a complete answer but I don't think you should include the I(0) in the johansen test. The test doesn't "know" that the one variable is I(0) so including it, in informal terms, will just mess everything up. Just run it on the three that are (1).

Comment: mlofton is right. You may find some closely related questions on Cross Validated. By now I have answered close to 10 of them, I think.